# Грудь и груда

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Увидела такую вот забавную надпись.
Речь тут идет о том, чтобы не собирали снег в груды. Но вот интересно, "грудь" и "груда" - однокоренные слова или нет?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ

ГРУДА, - Большая куча чего-н. Г.  камней. Г. книг.  Свалить вещи в груду (грудой).

СГРУДИТЬСЯ  сов. (разг.).  Собраться  в тесную  группу, в кучу,  образовать толпу. С.  у входа. Вдали сгрудились горы (перен.).

Вероятно, форма "не грудь" - это своеобразное "развитие значений"  для глагола "сгрудиться": сгрудиться - сгрудить - грудить - не грудь.

Грудь, груда - это, действительно, родственные слова общеславянского происхождения. Груда -  это возвышение, кочка, куча. Грудь буквально - также возвышенность, является  экспрессивным наименованием , которое стало применяться вместо существительного "перси".